# Find value and expand it to the grouping in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I need to transform pandas toy-dataframe like this (basically group by `entity`, find the value of `v` for which `df['gr'] == 'x'` and "expand" that value to the entire grouping):

```
entity  gr  v
0   A   x   1
1   A   y   2
2   A   z   3
3   B   z   4
4   B   x   5
5   B   y   6
```

to this form:

```
    entity  gr  v   new
0   A       x   1   1
1   A       y   2   1
2   A       z   3   1
3   B       z   4   5
4   B       x   5   5
5   B       y   6   5
```

Here is my solution:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'entity': ['A', 'A', 'A','B', 'B', 'B'], 'gr': ['x', 'y', 'z', 'z', 'x', 'y'], 'v': [1,2,3,4,5,6]})

df['new'] = df.loc[df['gr'] == 'x', 'v']
df['new'] = df.groupby('entity')['new'].ffill().bfill().astype(int)
```

but I wonder, if a better, more concise or idiomatic approach exists to this problem?

Slight variation on this problem, instead of `df['gr'] == 'x'`, different mask `df['gr'] == df['different_column']`

Comment: instead of the fill chaining, you could use `first` : ``df.groupby('entity')['new'].transform('first')``

Comment: As @jezrael says, should we safely assume that within each groupby 'entity', there is exactly one and only one row for which `df['gr'] == 'x'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If always match only one value or no value per `entity` is possible filter first, then convert `entity` to index and use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df['new'] = df['entity'].map(df[df['gr'] == 'x'].set_index('entity')['v'])

print (df)
  entity gr  v  new
0      A  x  1    1
1      A  y  2    1
2      A  z  3    1
3      B  z  4    5
4      B  x  5    5
5      B  y  6    5
```

Your solution should be changed by [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) in [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['new'] = (df.assign(new = df['v'].where(df['gr'] == 'x'))
               .groupby('entity')['new'].transform('first'))

print (df)
  entity gr  v  new
0      A  x  1  1.0
1      A  y  2  1.0
2      A  z  3  1.0
3      B  z  4  5.0
4      B  x  5  5.0
5      B  y  6  5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

After looking into answers, I've noticed alternative solution based on "join":

```
df['new'] = pd.merge(df, df[df['gr'] == 'x'], how='left', on=['entity'], suffixes=(None, '_new'))['v_new']
```

Comment: `pd.merge(df, ...` can more simply be written `df.merge(...)`